# Recommendations on Introducing Adopted Rabbit to my other pets

Tags: rabbits, introducing-pets

I just adopted a Silver (breed type) bunny and I would like to buy some other animals like dogs and other rabbits. I don't know her age and it would be nice to know what animals she could be familiar or at least get along with. (The most common ones for instance other rabbits, dogs, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I introduced my neutered female rabbit successfully with my older neutered male rabbit - I started off by having them in separate runs, next to each other and then supervised them together in "neutral territory".

In my experience, male and female rabbits get along together best (obviously after being neutered!) however I have also had 2 males together before. The trick is to gradually introduce them slowly - there are rabbit adoption companies that can help with this; you can take your bunny to them and they will help them bond in a neutral area.

My bunnies have also become friendly with my neighbour's cats but they have never met a dog! I would be a little concerned about a dog, unless you had it as a puppy and it grew up around the rabbit.